# Django many to many field add with through model fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have the models below, and I want to add a member to a group in a view. How could I do this, also adding the `date_joined` and `invite_reason` correctly. I am using forms without the generics views.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the reltationship you have to base your form on the relationship model:

```py
class MembershipForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['person', 'group', 'date_joined']
        model = Membership
```

This form will be composed of a select for the persons, a select for the group and a datefield for the date_joined